# Android Form for many extra details

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

This might already be described somewhere. However, I do not really know what to search for.

The feature I'm looking for is when you have a form where you can add more details. For example, there could be a field for adding your email address. However, if you want to add another email address you could click on a button and it will display another input field.

Ie

```
Name  [     ]
Email [     ]
[ADD]
```

Then after clicking add you would have

```
Name  [     ]
Email [     ]
Email [     ]
[ADD]
```

Thanks

Comment: you have to add layoutparams through coding....

Comment: search for adding views to the layout programmatically

Comment: Does anyone know if this feature has a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this simple example is how you can add an edittext when the button is clicked in your code:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
EditText et = new EditText(this);
ll.addView(et);
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code will help you to add edittext when button is clicked...

LinearLayout linearH = new LinearLayout(context);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams edtTextParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f);
EditText edtText =new EditText(context);
linearH.addView(edtText , edtTextParams);